# Closing mouth on coffin plane

Tags: tools, hand-planing, hand-tools

I have a Scioto coffin plane whose mouth is a little on the wide side. I'd like to glue a piece of wood inside the front of the throat to close it up, but I don't know if rubbing end grain against the face of my work is the best idea. Is there another way?

Comment: You could certainly glue in a cross-grain piece. Or simply ensure it stays level with or just inside the bottom of the plane...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe people generally use an [inlay](http://lumberjocks.com/Dcase/blog/27619) on the sole to repair or close up the mouth.